# Jest unit test wont await axios response

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, jestjs, axios

I am unit testing my vue-electron project using jest. In a given test i fake a button click to set off a chain of events. Somewhere in that chain i do an axios request to a server, receiving data. However, the test does not await the result and simply goes on and than crashes because the results are not there yet.

First of all i made sure the parameters and the adress of the request where correct, which they were. After that i tried if 'axios' was defined in the component while i was testing is, which was also the case. Than i made sure that if that request was sent, the right response was receiver, which also was the case. And ofcourse i made my test async, hoping that it now would await the results, this was not the case.

Component:

```
async functionInChain(){
const response = await axios({
      url: myUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      params: {
        // bind params
      },
    })
    .then((resp: any) => {
        // this goes wrong
    })
}
```

test:

```
describe('component.vue', async() => {
test('call runBot() and see if it reacts', async() => {
    wrapper.find('v-btn.button-i-use').trigger('click')
    /*later on i expect a value to be true, however it never is. 
By setting different "checkpoints" i found out things go wrong in the axios request.*/
  })
})
```

I do not get any errors on it, it just wont work

Comment: The question doesn't contain all relevant code. functionInChain is not the whole component. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not a big expert on jest and the code you've provided is quite minimal but the issue that jumps out to me is your use of `await` and promises.

Async and await syntax was introduced as a bit of sugar to make promises nicer. You no longer need to use `.then` on your function call if you're using `await`. Instead you carry on your code after the `await`. So your component code should look more like the following.

**Old code:**

```
async functionInChain(){
  const response = await axios({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    params: {
      // bind params
    },
  })
  .then((resp: any) => {
      // continue
  })
}
```

**New code:**

```
async functionInChain(){
  const response = await axios({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    params: {
      // bind params
    },
  })

  // continue, as if you were now in the ".then" function, because you "await"ed.
}
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, it would be worth updating your question with a complete example that we can run ourselves. To do this you should create a minimal piece of code that reproduces the issue and post that (not your whole code solution).

Comment: The remark regarding `then` is correct but this isn't an answer. Could be a comment. These snippets are fully interchangeable. The real issue is that a promise from functionInChain wasn't awaited in tests.

Comment: I think it's probably fair to say this isn't a correct answer if that's the case, but given the lack of code I believe this is a fair attempt at answering it.